# How to extract PDF document from SAP GUI? (scripting)

Tags: vba, scripting, sap-gui

I am trying to extract a PDF document from SAP, however, I am stuck with the second part of the code where I need to initiate the Save As sequence.

The first part of the code involves connecting to SAP and querying specific invoice number, followed by a few lines of code where I am trying to attach to the second SAP window containing the PDF document. The trick is using the Send Keys to save the actual file.

```
Sub DocumentExtraction()

    Dim varResponse As Variant 'Prompts the user if macro should be run.
        varResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to run extraction macro?", vbYesNo, "Warning!")
        If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI") 'Obtains SAP GUI Scripting object.
    Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Obtains currently running SAP GUI.
    Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Obtains the first system currently connected.
    Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Obtains the first session (window) on that connection.

    ' SAP scripting starts here.

    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nFB03"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRF05L-BELNR").Text = "930502016"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").Text = "7360"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRF05L-GJAHR").Text = "2019"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRF05L-GJAHR").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRF05L-GJAHR").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").pressContextButton "%GOS_TOOLBOX"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_VIEW_ATTA"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell

    Set session = SAPCon.Children(1) 'Obtains the second session (window) on current connection.

    session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").SetFocus

End Sub
```

I have found a similar post on the SAP support page, however, the suggested solution does not seem to work - an object does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA function which works well to save a PDF document generated by SAP. The document need to be visible using tcode "PDF!" (which is working for invoices VF03, delivery notes VL03N, orders VA03, ...)

```
Function getFilePath(session As Variant) As String
Dim fileLink As String
Dim i As Integer

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "PDF!"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

fileLink = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlHTML/shellcont/shell").BrowserHandle.LocationURL

fileLink = Replace(fileLink, "file:///", "")

For i = 1 To 255
    fileLink = Replace(fileLink, "%" & Right("00" & Hex(i), 2), Chr(i))
Next i

getFilePath = fileLink
End Function
```

You have to call this function just before you normally type "PDF!" in SAP (which is performed by the code above). You also need to pass your SAP `session` object to the function.

Answer (score -1):

An easy workaround was to disable Adobe PDF Reader in Internet Explorer by navigating to Internet Explorer/Tools/Internet Options/Programs/Manage add-ons/select All add-ons/disable Adobe PDF Reader.

Then use the code below after clicking on the document and it opens the open/save/close window.

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:15")
SendKeys "%s" 'ALT + S initiates save as procedure.

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
SendKeys ExtractFolderPath & ExtractFileName 'File name and path are entered.

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
SendKeys "{F3}" 'Closes Document Viewer window.

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
session.findById("wnd[1]").Close 'Closes Attachment List window.
```

Comment: I would not recommend to use `Sendkeys` as one cannot rely on it. In your case what happens if 15s resp 2s is not enough time to wait for the SAPGUI to show the dialog.

Comment: I agree it's far from ideal. I added a piece of code though to look into the download folder and report back if the file is actually present :) I also have a code to pick up the SAP status bar text for more clarity on why the file is not extracted. But, as you said, it's not the best option.

Comment: Then you do not have SAPGUI 7.30 PL8 or higher because with that version my code above should work and then no need to use `Sendkeys`.

Comment: We actually have SAP GUI 740 and I have deselected above scripting option. I get the message that this function is not supported for document <Billing document>, which is the name of pretty much all of the documents I'm trying to extract. And you were right about Send Keys, once I switched to smaller screen (used two screens to code), it did not work so definitely unreliable.